# Split String on the multiple spaces using python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to split the string on multiple spaces but not on single space.

I have tried string.split() but it splits on every single space

here is my code

```
string='hi i am    kaveer  and i am a   student'   
string.split()
```

i expected the result

`['hi i am','kaveer','and i am a','student']`

but actual result is

`['hi','i','am','kaveer','and','i','am','a','student']`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can make a regular expression that matches 2 or more spaces and use [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html#re.split) to split on the match:

```
import re

s='hi i am    kaveer'   
re.split(r'\s{2,}', s)
```

**result**

```
['hi i am', 'kaveer']
```

Comment: thanks, it worked on the previous problem please revisit the question it is becoming more difficult

Comment: @VeerSingh this works on your new string too. Have you tried it?

Comment: can you tell me how it works or any resource to understand it

Comment: @VeerSingh it's a regular expression which is a pattern matcher. `\s` matches a space, `{2,}` modifies it to match two or more. If you google regular expression you will find lots of information.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to import anything, get rid of `regexp`. Enjoy real python.

```
>>> string='hi i am    kaveer  and i am a   student'   
>>> new_list = list(map(lambda strings: strings.strip(), string.split('  ')))
['hi i am', '', 'kaveer', 'and i am a', 'student']

# remove empty string from list.
>>> list(filter(None, new_list))
['hi i am', 'kaveer', 'and i am a', 'student']

# Or you could combine it all of these on one line,
# Of course you could loose readability.


>> list(filter(None, list(map(lambda strings: strings.strip(), string.split('  ')))))
```

Comment: Is calling 7 functions to split a string really better than a simple regexp? It's also not clear why using python's standard library isn't "real" python.

Comment: You have just imported whole `re` library, which could be simplified just using   python's built in functions . Python's `re` module is based on PCRE.

Comment: Your code is great and works, but I'm sorry, *real python* means readable easy code. Don't see what so bad about a simple regex...

Comment: Yeah your code is just great, just simple two lines. I just did without using library. Maybe it may help others.