# Counting groups of words in a line (counting columns where some titles are more than one word)

Tags: python, split, spyder, delimiter

I have a txt file of data and I am trying to count the number of columns. My approach is to count the titles of the first line using:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(Len(line.split()))
```

However, some of the titles are more than one word, so this is returning a higher number than what it should be. The titles are also not separated by a fixed number of spaces, as I already considered giving split an argument of a certain number of spaces.

Is there a way to get it to only count words that are separated by more than one space?

Here is the table I am working with:

[image: table]

If this is not possible, is there a better way to approach this?

Comment: you could try `re.split(r'\s{2,}', line)` (requires an `import re`) which splits things separated by 2 or more whitespaces

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Split String on the multiple spaces using python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56823117/split-string-on-the-multiple-spaces-using-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression should do it:

```
re.split('\W\W+', line)
```