# Python - Before adding text to a file check it doesn't already exist - How?

Tags: python

I need to add device names and device IP addresses to the bottom of a text file each time a new device goes live so I can connect via name instead of IP.

My problem is how to check the device I'm adding doesn't already exist, if it does exist then the logic should be to ignore, otherwise it should be added to the bottom of the specified file.

I have managed to add the required text to the file but on running the code for a second time the text is added again rather than ignoring.

Any text specified in lines that already exists in the file called Device_Names should not be added.

I've seen a lot of examples that look for specific key words in the existing text file which returns true/false parameters and/or prints to screen but this isn't sustainable long term. Can someone point me in the right direction on how to go about it? I've used and if/else functions but not getting very far.

I currently have:

```
lines = [
'\n\device.1                             A                       10.10.10.10'
'\n\n'
'device.2                             A                       11.11.11.11'
'\n\n'
'device.3                             A                       12.12.12.12']


with open ("Device_Names", "a+") as f:
    
    for line in lines:
        
        f.write(line)

f.close()
```

Comment: Parse the text file once during startup to create a dictionary of known devices. Then check against the dictionary.

Comment: _but on running the code for a second time the text is added again rather than ignoring_ If you don't show us the code you tried, we can't point out your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It's really simple - You need to analize the data inside file and check it.

I suggest you to write data in csv format e.g. row: 'device_name, device_ip\n' - this will facilitate data analysis.

You can also sort your device list by name or ip and optimize searches or use pandas etc.

example file content:

```
device_0, 10.20.30.40
device_1, 11.23.33.9
```

e.g. code:

```py
new_ip = "10.20.30.40"
new_name = "device_2"

with open(file_name, "r") as f_r:
    for line in f_r:
        name, ip = line.split(",")
        if ip == new_ip: # or name == new_name
            break
    else:
        with open(file_name, "a") as f_a:
            # f'' looks better but is slower then adding
            f_a.write(new_name+","+new_ip+"\n")
```

Comment: Thanks, unsure if I can change this to CSV as the file is being used for DNS and I don't know enough currently on how that works behind the scenes

Answer (score 0):

You can use dictionary to keep track of added items like below.

```
dic={}
with open ("Device_Names", "a+") as f:  
    for line in lines:
        if line not in dic:
            dic[line] =1
            f.write(line)
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be easier if your text file was a CSV instead of using a trillion spaces like you've shown.

```
from pathlib import Path

cwd = Path().resolve() # Current working directory
file_path = cwd.joinpath("devices.txt")

# Read the existing file
with open(file_path, 'r') as f:
    # make a list, each item represents one line
    text = f.readlines()
    # text = ['device.1                             A                       10.10.10.10\n',
    #         'device.2                             A                       11.11.11.11\n',
    #         'device.3                             A                       12.12.12.12']

# Now we want to break each line into name:address pairs, but all of 
# those extra spaces pose a small challenge. 

# This does not work:
# text[0].split(" ") 
# >>> ['device.1', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', 'A', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '', '10.10.10.10']

devices = {}
# I don't know regex, so I lifted this expression from https://stackoverflow.com/a/56823175/6030926 
for line in text:
    parts = re.split(r'\s{2,}', line) # ['device.1', 'A', '10.10.10.10']
    name = parts[0]
    addr = parts[2].strip() # strip() gets rid of trailing \n
    devices[name] = addr # Add this device to our dictionary

print(f"{devices=}")        

# Now you can search for devices
for dev in ["device.3", "device.4"]:

    if dev in devices.keys():
        print(f"{dev} already exists")
    else:
        # Open the file for appending and write your line.
        print(f"{dev} doesn't exist")
```

Output:

```
devices={'device.1': '10.10.10.10', 'device.2': '11.11.11.11', 'device.3': '12.12.12.12'}
device.3 already exists 
device.4 doesn't exist
```

Comment: Thanks, unsure if I can change to CSV as the file is to be used for DNS, I'll have to check a few other things with Networks first